# MEAN: nodejs server for Angular App - How do i serve angular routes

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express, mean-stack

Here is my node `server.js` it is in the project root with its own npm config. All Angular files are in `/client` hence after `ng build` the dist will be at `client/dist`

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const colors = require('colors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = process.env.port||'3200';

// init "app"
const app = express();

app.use(cors({origin: `http://localhost:4200`}));

// angular entry point
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/dist')));

//parse incoming data before routes
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// api routes
app.use('/api',require('./api/api'));

// error middleware
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log(`${err}`.red.bold)
    res.status(422).send({error: err.message });
});

// listen
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log(`app running on ${PORT}...`.magenta);
});
```

When I go to the server `http://localhost:3200/` I see my angular app. and when I go to `http://localhost:3200/api/someExpressRoute` I get my api functions. great

Now I need to figure out how to serve angular routes. for example `http://localhost:3200/about` is part of my angular single page app. But when I go to that url the server doesnt know what to do.

How do I configure this server to handle `http://localhost:3200/*` as an angular route that is served from index?

Comment: you configure your server to always serve `index.html` for all routes except for anything under `/api`. Angular will then sort out the routing on the client side.

Comment: @samherrmann I know but how?

Comment: Ah my apologies, I missed the end where you did specified "... served from index". I'll let someone more familiar with express answer. (maybe this is a helpful resource: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I serve my angular application via nodejs:

```
var express = require('express'),
   path = require('path'),
   fs = require('fs');
var compression = require('compression');
var app = express();
var staticRoot = __dirname + '/';
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(compression());
/* other middleware */

/* place any backend routes you have here */    

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    //if the request is not html then move along
    var accept = req.accepts('html', 'json', 'xml');
    if (accept !== 'html') {
        return next();
    }

    // if the request has a '.' assume that it's for a file, move along
    var ext = path.extname(req.path);
    if (ext !== '') {
        return next();
    }

    fs.createReadStream(staticRoot + 'index.html').pipe(res);

});

app.use(express.static(staticRoot));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('app running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

When serving the application, ensure all of your frontend dist files are in the same folder as this file (which I call `index.js`)

Comment: great. Angular Routes work. Can you show me how I would do `http://localhost:5000/test.php`?

Comment: If you'd like to use PHP files, you're going to need to run a PHP server like apache. You should consider sticking to a single backend language, whether that be only PHP or NodeJS

Comment: php wasnt my choice. I will just host it elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

## Serving Angular application with NodeJs Express

If you want to serve your angular app with NodeJs you need to serve the `index.html` file of your Angular build by using the `res.sendFile()` function of expressJs. See [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.sendFile) for more details.

Before, you need to ensure your Express built-in middleware called `static` point to your a folder containing all the files builded by Angular during the compilation (genarally it's the `dist` folder of your frontend app)

## Serving Angular Route

If you want your Angular Router working, you need to redirect all your incoming request to the frontend. You can also add some verification like `@Syntactic Fructose` suggest to do with the request checking for html or file.

## Exemple

Just a basic exemple of how you can implement that

```
import express, { Request, Response , Application } from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import http from 'http';
import { router } from './path/to/my/api/routes';

const app = express();

const frontendFiles = "path/to/your/frontend/dist/folder";

// Point static middleware to your Angular build
app.use(express.static(frontendFiles));

// Your api routes
app.use('/api', router);

// Do whatever you want like
// app.get('/someStuff', (req, res) => {...}

// Then your last route is
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(frontendFiles, '/index.html'));
});

// Serve your app
const httpServer = new http.Server(app);
const port = 3000;
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log(`app fire on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

###### Comment

For more deployment simplicity, i suggest you to use `.env` variable for the `frontendFiles` variable.